# How to call a coldfusion query in jquery tab click function

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I wrote a jquery function . um calling to a coldfusion query to dynamically append elements to a spam but this is not working . can any one tell what s wrong?

```
$('a.clikceble',$this).click(function(){
  <cfloop query="GET_ALL_STUDENT_INFO_QUERY">
            alert("inside");
            $(".quick_time_dl a").attr("href", "index.cfm?event=location.index&section=download&topic_id=<cfoutput>#URLDecode(url.topic_id)#</cfoutput>&video_id=<cfoutput>#URLDecode(url.video_id)#</cfoutput>&video_name=<cfoutput>#URLDecode(url_mov)#</cfoutput>&video_type=lif_mov"); 
            $(".win_media_dl a").attr("href", "index.cfm?event=location.index&section=download&topic_id=<cfoutput>#URLDecode(url.topic_id)#</cfoutput>&video_id=<cfoutput>#URLDecode(url.video_id)#</cfoutput>&video_name=<cfoutput>#URLDecode(url_wmv)#</cfoutput>&video_type=lif_wmv");
            <cfif len(url_pdf)>
                $("#url_pdf").attr("href", "../assets/teaching_notes_pdf/<cfoutput>#URLDecode(url_pdf)#</cfoutput>");
                $(".pdf_desc").append($("#url_pdf"));
                alert($(".pdf_desc").append($("#url_pdf")));
                $("#url_pdf").show();
            </cfif>
            <cfif len(pdf_transcript)>
                $("#pdf_transaction").attr("href", "../assets/teaching_notes_transcripts/<cfoutput>#URLDecode(pdf_transcript)#</cfoutput>");
                $(".pdf_desc").append($("#pdf_transaction"));
                alert($(".pdf_desc").append($("#pdf_transaction")));
                $("pdf_transaction").show();
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>
```

Comment: I think you are trying to mixing up coldfusion code and javascript code. Good idea to check this is look into your generated code or post your generated browser code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this, when you click your tab, call your coldfusion page via ajax method. Just create a coldfusion page with the query, and returs the results via JSON format. You can use jquery ajax function with json data type, then loop over your result set and finally append it to your DOM. A simple google search for 'jquery coldfusion' returns lot  of results, such as "[Easy AJAX using ColdFusion, jQuery and CFCs](http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2011/3/3/Easy-AJAX-using-ColdFusion-jQuery-and-CFCs)".

Answer (score 0):

In this code, first the server side code will execute(the cfloop, cfif,etc.) and will create the client side java script. IN your case if the query(GET_ALL_STUDENT_INFO_QUERY) has 3 records then after processing the server side it will create the script three times and return it to the browser, but it will not processes any query operation(server side code) at the click event. To processes a server side operation on the click event(from the client side) you need to use the Ajax.